Confused by the inputs of scipy.signal.ShortTimeFFT
I'm confused by the 'hop' and 'fs' inputs in the documentation.
"hop int:
The increment in samples, by which the window is shifted in each step."
is this asking the number of samples between each sample of the given dataset? For example, if I give it a dataset with 1000 entries, and I tell it 100, it will perform an fft on 10 sections of a 100 points?
"fs float:
Sampling frequency of input signal and window. Its relation to the sampling interval T is T = 1 / fs."
Is this asking for the frequency that the provided sample was taken at?

Short-time Fourier Transform cuts your signal into smaller parts, known as  windows/frames. Those windows have their size, often referred as frame_size/window_size/window_length. There is also parameter hop_size that defines how many offset samples are between consecutive frames.

IMAGE SOURCE: Area-Efficient Short-Time Fourier Transform Processor for Time–Frequency Analysis of Non-Stationary Signals
fs is sampling frequency, which is not that important when it comes to SFFT computation. It is very important if you define other parameters (window size, hop size) in seconds rather than in number of samples. Inside the stft function it will be used to compute how many samples are in a window of e.g. 20ms.
window_size_in_samples = int(np.round(sampling_frequency * window_size_in_seconds))


Have you read the documentation? The function does ask for a window (win). You can create this window with scipy.signal.windows. I'd start with a Hamming window.
Overlap is just the window length minus the hop

Thank you! This was super helpful. How do you define the window/overlap length? The function only requests hop.
The function produces an object in vscode that I can't really read, though it looks like I can call out the methods and attributes in the documentation to get the data out of it.
so 'f' is the frequency data, do I multiply those by fac_magnitude to get the amplitudes? or another set of values? The documentation just says "the STFT values".

@Jdip It appears I misunderstood the function, I am supposed to input only an individual window rather than the whole dataset? So if I want to analyze a whole dataset, I need to call the function multiple times?

@TannerBurton You define window/overlap length as big as you want. Bigger the window, larger frequency resolution. Smaller the window, better time resolution. Smaller hop gives you more "smooth" image along time axis. You can think of hop as sampling interval. But instead of samples you get whole spectra

@TannerBurton Here comes ambiguity of term "window". After you cut signal into windows/frames, you multiply those windows/frames by window function (win parameter, represented as an array), e.g. Hamming window Jdip mentioned. This is almost always done, to help with boundary problems of Discrete Fourier Transform. So, window is referred to as parts of the input signal AND as function/samples you multiply those parts with.

@dankal444 If you generate a window using scipy.signal.windows() and that is what gets plugged into ShortTimeFFT(), where does the dataset get input? It doesn't look like the windows function takes a dataset, just an input of the number of entries in the dataset.

@TannerBurton what do you mean by dataset and input? I have trouble understanding what you are asking

@dankal444 I'm trying to run the stft on a dataset/signal like the one I described in this question, however, it sounds like that dataset isn't being given to the function anywhere. Where in the function do you input the signal you're trying to analyze?

@TannerBurton term "dataset" is misleading, use signal.  Take a look at documentation and line Sx = SFT.stft(x)  # perform the STFT

@dankal444 So the ShortTimeFFT() function doesn't actually perform the fft, but instead generates some form of blueprint, that you then apply when calling .stft([signal])?
I apologize if it appears like I'm not reading the documentation, I promise I am, but am finding it very confusing.

Yes, not sure if blueprint is best analogy but yes, some object that is later used to perform stft (short-time fourier transform)
